# Update textbox value based on combox selection in uwp using mvvm

Tags: mvvm, uwp

I have view with a combobox and five textboxes which is used to add new customer. To add the customer, declared the properties in my viewmodel and bind those properties to all respective textboxes text properties like,

View:

```
<StackPanel>
   <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomers}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
   <Textbox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
   <Textbox Text="{Binding Age}"/>
   <Textbox Text="{Binding Phone}"/>
   <Textbox Text="{Binding Address}"/>
   <Textbox Text="{Binding Email}"/>
<StackPanel>
```

ViewModel:

```
    public class myviewmodel
    {

     private string _name;
     public string Name
     {
         get { return _name;}
         set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
     } 
      private string _age;
     public string Age
     {
         get { return _age;}
         set { _age = value; OnPropertyChanged("Age"); }
     } 

    private Customer _selectedCustomer;
    public Customer SelectedCustomer
    {
        get { return _selectedCustomer; }
        set { selectedCustomer = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCustomer"); }
    } 


    }
```

I will load the existing customer names to the comboxbox. To update the existing 
        customer details, if i select a customer name in combobox the selected customer details 
        should bind in textboxes so that i can easily update them. but the textbox text 
        properties are already used to add the new customers. so how to add and update the 
        customers using the same textboxes??

Comment: i refered this link already but they explained only how to change textbox values based on combox selection. but in my case adding new customer and updating  existing customer using the same textboxes.. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9cbd2f3a-21e7-4700-887d-b27d4d74748d/update-textbox-based-on-combobox-selection-in-mvvm?forum=wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Textboxes' Bindings are not set to the SelectedCustomer. Give this a try.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>

<Grid Visibility="{Binding ExistingCustomer, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
    <Textbox Text="{Binding SelectedCustomer.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Textbox Text="{Binding SelectedCustomer.Age, Mode=TwoWay}}"/>
    <Textbox Text="{Binding SelectedCustomer.Phone, Mode=TwoWay}}"/>
    <Textbox Text="{Binding SelectedCustomer.Address, Mode=TwoWay}}"/>
    <Textbox Text="{Binding SelectedCustomer.Email, Mode=TwoWay}}"/>
</Grid>
<Grid Visibility="{Binding ExistingCustomer, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
    <Textbox Text="{Binding Customer.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Textbox Text="{Binding Customer.Age, Mode=TwoWay}}"/>
    <Textbox Text="{Binding Customer.Phone, Mode=TwoWay}}"/>
    <Textbox Text="{Binding Customer.Address, Mode=TwoWay}}"/>
    <Textbox Text="{Binding Customer.Email, Mode=TwoWay}}"/>
</Grid>
```

And here is the code for the converter

```
public class VisibilityConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
    {
        bool displayControl = (bool)value;

        if (displayControl == true)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Be sure to reference the namespace where your converter lives in your page resources

Comment: you gave the solution for how to bind the values to textboxes based on combobox selection.. thats ok. and thats my one task. another one is through those textboxes i need to add new values to the database. so how can i bind the properties which have been declared in the viewmodel to the textbox?? @Allen Ruflolo

Comment: So you are trying to use the same text boxes to accomplish two things correct? You want them to display the information of the selected customer from the dropdown OR display information of a new user that will be added to the database. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.. want to do those two things.. @Allen Rufolo.. Can we do like so?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Perhaps include a converter that will show/hide a grid based on whether or not a customer is selected and will be edited vs a new customer that will be added.

Comment: Done. Thanks for spending time.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [Interaction Behaviors](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/30/xaml-behaviors-open-source-and-on-uwp/#1VIWFO4wKV510Hi9.97) this can be achieved.

First of all, the Behaviors SDK is not built-in UWP, but has to be downloaded separately from NuGet.

You can use the following command to install it:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed
```

Or just use the NuGet Package Manager and search for `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed`.

After you install, you can just add the XAML using statements to the top of your page:

```xml
<Page ...
xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core" />
```

You do not need to create another property `SelectedCustomer` if you are always going to bind your TextBox from Combobox SelectedItem. Unless you intend to use `SelectedCustomer` for some other code behind work.

Below is how you achieve your `TextBox` Text without `SelectedCustomer` Property.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=stkData}" PropertyName="DataContext" Value="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboBox}"  />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ComboBox>

<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,20" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboBox}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" PlaceholderText="Name" Name="Name"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Age, Mode=TwoWay}" PlaceholderText="Age" Name="Age"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Phone, Mode=TwoWay}" PlaceholderText="Phone" Name="Phone"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Address, Mode=TwoWay}" PlaceholderText="Address" Name="Address"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay}" PlaceholderText="Email" Name="Email"/>
</StackPanel>
```

If you notice, I bound the data from `comboBox` `SelectedItem` Property to `StackPanel` DataContext and then Individual Properties directly to Text of your `TextBox`. This will take care of your `ComboBox` Binding to `TextBox`. Mode should always be `TwoWay` so that data can be updated when user Modifies Existing Customer Details.

Now after this is done, When you want to add a new Customer Info with current TextBoxes, You want to clear the selection without changing the current value. Below is how I added a Button with Interaction Behaviors.

And use the `Clicked` action to clear the `TextBox` Text. In UWP XAML you can use empty string as value and it works as expected.

```xml
<Button Content="+" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0" Tag="{Binding EmptyClass, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="btnNew">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
            <core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=stkData}" PropertyName="DataContext" Value="{Binding Tag, ElementName=btnNew, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
            <core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=comboBox}" PropertyName="SelectedIndex" Value="-1"  />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

Also Note I am making the selected Index of `ComboBox` to -1 so that selected Data cannot be updated.

And now the saving portion should be pretty simple and straight forward. Below is a button that i used with `TappedEvent`

```
private void saveBtn_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    model.Customers.Add(model.EmptyClass);
    model.EmptyClass = new MyClass();
}
```

You can see I am reinstantiating `EmptyClass` Again so that old bound data can be cleared off.

**Below is Complete XAML**

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App15"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Text="using:System.Text"
    x:Class="App15.MainPage"
    xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    Loaded="Page_Loaded"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid Margin="0,100,0,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0">
                    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            <core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=stkData}" PropertyName="DataContext" Value="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboBox}"  />
                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </ComboBox>
                <Button Content="+" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0" Tag="{Binding EmptyClass, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="btnNew">
                    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                            <core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=stkData}" PropertyName="DataContext" Value="{Binding Tag, ElementName=btnNew, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
                            <core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=comboBox}" PropertyName="SelectedIndex" Value="-1"  />
                        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,20" Name="stkData">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" PlaceholderText="Name"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Age, Mode=TwoWay}" PlaceholderText="Age" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Phone, Mode=TwoWay}" PlaceholderText="Phone" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Address, Mode=TwoWay}" PlaceholderText="Address" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay}" PlaceholderText="Email" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Button Name="saveBtn" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Tapped="saveBtn_Tapped"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Below is Complete Code Behind**

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;

namespace App15
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DataContext = model;
        }

        private void saveBtn_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            model.Customers.Add(model.EmptyClass);
            model.EmptyClass = new MyClass();
        }
    }
}
```

**Below is Complete View Model**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Customers = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
        EmptyClass = new MyClass();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Customers.Add(new MyClass()
            {
                Name = "Item" + (i + 1).ToString(),
                Address = "Address" + (i + 1).ToString(),
                Age = "20" + (i + 1).ToString(),
                Email = "Test" + (i + 1).ToString() + "@test.com",
                Phone = (9876543210 + i).ToString()
            });
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> Customers { get; set; }
    public MyClass EmptyClass { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I know there is a way to even use Save Option in MVVM But I did not get the opportunity to use `DelegateCommand`. But if you would like to try it yourself, Check this [Video by Jerry Nixon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cB7KdYPQw1k) for Reference

Comment: Actually thanks for spending the time. But unfortunately, if i add the new data through textboxes then the added name is not visible in the combobox?? and one more thing, i want follow mvvm pattern so if i add the new data through textboxes how should i pass the data from view to viewmodel? (know that through binding its possible. but textboxes "Text" properties are already engaged to show the combobox selected item. so how should i do?? @AVK Naidu